# variance of sliding window in image

Tags: c++, opencv, variance

I work on traffic sign detection, firstly I am applied a segmentation on RGB image to obtain red channel image as it is illustrated in image 1:

[image]

Secondely I try to find homogeneous region to eliminate not interested region (not a traffic sign) by calculating the variance of sliding window above the image

I use this code but I have always exception

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    IplImage *image1;

    if ((image1 = cvLoadImage("segmenter1/00051.jpg", 0)) == 0)
        return NULL;

    int rows = image1->width;
    int cols = image1->height;

    Mat image = Mat::zeros(cols, rows, CV_32FC1);
    double x = 0;
    double temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            temp = cvGet2D(image1, j, i).val[0];

            x = temp / 255;

            image.at<float>(j, i) = x;
            x = image.at<float>(j, i);
        }
    }

    int k = 16;
    double seuil = 0.0013;
    CvScalar blanc;//pixel blanc
    blanc.val[0] = 255;
    cv::Scalar mean, stddev; //0:1st channel, 1:2nd channel and 2:3rd channel

    for (int j = 0; j < rows - k; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cols - k; i++)
        {
            double som = 0;
            double var = 0;
            double t = 0;

            for (int jj = j; jj < k+j; jj++)
            {
                for (int ii = i; ii < k+i; ii++)
                {
                    t = image.at<float>(jj, ii);
                    som = som + t;
                    t = t*t;
                    var =var+ t;
                }
            }

            som = som / (k*k);
            if (som>0.18){
                var = (var / (k*k)) - (som*som);
                if (var < seuil)
                    cvSet2D(image1, j, i, blanc);
            }
        }
    }

    char stsave[80];
    cvSaveImage("variance/00051.jpg", image1);
    cv::waitKey(0);                                         
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should tell us which exception and where. Right now we can only guess. Try to make a [mcve] if you want a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without the specific exception, I can only guess it is `out_of_range`. According to opencv docs, `cvGet2D` and `cvSet2D` parameters are `image, y, x` which effectively translates to `image, rows, cols`. You have flipped the definition of `rows, cols` and have conflicting usage between the two loops. Maybe fix these and try again.